# SQL server avoid procedures parameter sniffing

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm getting slow performances from this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure01
  @date datetime2(7)
  AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[mc_object] AS [mc_object], 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (50) 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [mc_object], 
    1 AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[mc_object] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[BEM_EVT_FULL] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[date_reception] > @date
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[mc_object]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
)  AS [Limit1]
END
```

After doing some searching i've found that if declaring variables that way we will solve parameter sniffing issues.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure02
  @date datetime2(7)
  AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @myDate datetime2(7)
 SET @myDate = @date
 SELECT 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[mc_object] AS [mc_object], 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (50) 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [mc_object], 
    1 AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[mc_object] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[BEM_EVT_FULL] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[date_reception] > @myDate
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[mc_object]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
)  AS [Limit1]
END
```

But unfortunatly results still slow can i know if i'm missing something here

Comment: You keep cross-posting this...stop it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703962/stored-procedure-is-not-using-indexes/29704407#comment47545431_29704407

Comment: You're trying to combat parameter sniffing in EF.  Is this a stored procedure or are you executing directly from EF?

Comment: @Mark Sinkinson it's not the same post.

Comment: That's the result i got from sql server profiler after running the query in entity framework, i'm trying to figure out what's the problem localy in SSMS than i'll move to EF

Comment: Based on your question title I would assume you believe you have a bad parameter sniffing issue? Why do you believe that? Does it run faster with some parameters but slower with others? If not, and it runs slow for all, then you do not have a parameter sniffing issue.

Comment: It runs slow only for dateTime parameter  for others it works just fine.... :(

Comment: This is a fundamental drawback of directly executing from EF (and a reason why I DO NOT advocate using EF).  In EF you can't use query hints like OPTION(RECOMPILE) which may help this very problem.  I'd recommend trying to put this code into a stored procedure where you CAN use query hints.  Also, directly executing code via EF may open you up to SQL injection.

Comment: You suggest using native sql in stead of linq queries ?

Comment: Absolutely.  Imagine you have 200 different queries that an application can use.  Your DBA is not going to like troubleshooting this stuff as it's incredibly difficult to interpret what's actually happening. Look at all the aliases and imagine this code being larger (1000s of lines).  Take EF code, then write the same thing in SQL like you normally would, put them side by side and tell me which query you can easily understand.  It won't be that mess that EF generates, that's for sure.

Comment: Also, if your EF code goes sideways, guess who gets woken up at 330am?  You do, because the code is built in the application, is executed in the application layer instead of the DB level, and the DBA can't really do anything to change it.  Don't know about you, but I like to sleep at night.

Comment: I'will note this  thanks for your advice .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seriously, stop using Entity Framework. It's great for scaffolding a quick proof-of-concept, but in terms of Production systems, it's rubbish.

You also have a `SELECT TOP 50` without an order by. What order would you like the results to come back? What is `TOP`? The way it stands, you could get results in any order

In any case, start by rewriting your query

```
SELECT TOP 50 
  1 AS [C2], 
  mc_object, 
  COUNT(1) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[BEM_EVT_FULL] 
WHERE date_reception > @myDate 
GROUP BY mc_object
ORDER BY C1 DESC; -- Added an order
```

Make sure `date_reception` has an index that includes `mc_object`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_bemevtfull_datereception 
ON dbo.BEM_EVT_FULL(date_reception) 
INCLUDE (mc_object);
```

Comment: Okey i'm leaving EF event if it will cost me an amount of time.

Answer (score -1):

1. Directly use proc parametes in your queries (@date)
2. If you have un-even data distribution in your table, Parameter sniffing could hurt performance when the plan that was already in cache is used for your current execution, which is has different parameter value and the data distribution is drastically different for this parameter value. Say, 5 rows vs 1000 rows.

One of the ways you can overcome this is use option (recompile) for the particular query inside the proc that is giving performance issue due to parameter sniffing.

Comment: This code is generated in EF.  AFAIK, EF doesn't support the use of query hints.